# Children's fantasy book about creatures that can only venture outside in the day

Tags: story-identification

I read this book several times as a kid, and something made me think of it, and I wanted to read it again, but I can't find out anything about it anywhere. Googling every keyword I can think of hasn't turned up anything.

There are these creatures that live in a forest village. They need the day time to go out and gather food. At night they are safely in their houses. Anyone who is out at night will probably get eaten by evil creatures that can only come out in the dark. The problem is that the daylight has been shrinking and they have less time to gather food. Eventually they are stuck in a twilight where the dark creatures are able to come out, so nobody can get food, and the few people that try end up getting eaten. By the way, the cover I remember had a picture of the main character on it, and he looks a bit like the characters from *The Dark Crystal*, only with possibly blue mottled skin.

So our hero, a teenage boy, has to journey to the source of the light and fix it. First he has to visit an Elder creature of some kind in a castle to find out information. He travels through a forest and up a mountain to get there, and the creature tells him some things and also points out another castle in the middle of a desert where another elder creature lives who can provide more information.

The boy travels across the desert. He can run at a marathon pace -- very steadily and fast without using too much energy. He reaches the other castle, but I think the other elder is gone. He makes a friend here. He continues on toward the light source. There's a problem though; the friend can't run as fast as him, and they're in danger of running out of water/food because of not going fast enough.

They reach the light source, and it turns out to be a massive rotating disk with light on one side and dark on the other, so when the light is on top the dark is underground and it is day time, and vice versa. A bad guy has jammed a spanner or something in the mechanism underground so it has stopped turning, and is stuck on mainly dark. They have to fix it so it can turn again. There's a problem, though; the bad guy that did this tries to stop them, and also the light coming from the disk is so bright it could kill them even through blindfolds they've made. A vague memory tells me they free the disk and kill the bad guy, but they die in the process.

Comment: Which creatures from *The Dark Crystal*?

Comment: The Gelflings. In fact a long time ago, I had very spotty memories of the Dark Crystal (and didn't know its name) and I thought this book might have been the source of them (back when I still had a copy), except that some of the memories didn't quite align. (Later on I found the movie and worked out that was where the memories came from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't believe I just found it. I have been searching for this book for *years*, on and off. Today I thought I'd just have a few minutes googling for `novels like dark crystal`. After wading though pages and pages that are just about novelisations and comics of the movie, I found this thread on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/8lwah7/what_would_you_recommend_if_im_looking_for/).

And luckily I recognised that the title seemed familiar: [*Brog The Stoop*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2007033.Brog_The_Stoop).

> The Source of Light is failing...And for the Stoop who inhabit Drabwurld, the encroaching darkness brings a terrible danger. Their mortal enemies the Gork, led by the vicious Redeye, grow ever stronger as the Light fades slowly away. And it is only a matter of time before the Stoop are utterly destroyed...
>
> But there is one Stoop, who will not accept defeat. For Brog has the brave heart needed to find the Source of Light, and restore it to its former glory. And as he sets off on his perilous quest, the Stooplord, Klan the Golden, leads the Stoop in a final, and possibly fatal, battle against the Gork...
>
> <sub>[Fantastic Fiction, *Brog the Stoop* (1993)](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/books/w/w83441.htm)</sub>

If any kids or young teenagers see this answer, you should definitely give the book a go.